# How can I troubleshoot poor wifi performance?

Tags: wireless-networking, router, performance

I recently installed a new Gateway combined modem/router from Comcast/Xfinity.
Since then 3 of our devices (Macbook Pro, 2 iPads) connect fine but the other (3 year old HP laptop) exhibits the following symptoms:

1. After connecting to the wifi network, the first 1-3 browser requests are fast
2. After that they are crazy slow to the point of being unusable
3. If I disconnect from wifi and reconnect, the next couple of requests will be fast, slow thereafter
4. If I run network diagnostics, the following couple of requests will be fast, then slow after that
5. The signal always shows up as strong
6. Last night I connected to someone else's wifi and had no problems
7. When I plug into Ethernet, no problem

Comcast couldn't help!
Any clues?

Thanks very much

Comment: Sounds possible the wifi hardware in the HP is getting "tired", or there's a problem with Windows settings (assuming Windows, not Linux).  Do you have or can you get/borrow a USB wifi dongle you can connect on that machine to see if things are better with another wifi device?  That would narrow down between the hardware and a software/OS issue.

Comment: Thanks. The wifi dongle thing - I'd wondered about that. (And yes, it's Windows 7, meant to say)

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes problems are caused by devices which use the same frequencies as wifi (such as microwaves or old DECT phones). 
Sadly, you would need a spectrum analyzer to investigate this (like http://www.metageek.com/products/wi-spy/ )